# How to prevent the mobile keyboard from rearranging parts of the UI in React Native?

Tags: css, react-native

The mobile keyboard can create quite a mess on the screen when it opens up after you select an input. As an example here:

[Mobile keyboard rearranges parts of the user interface when it opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlI4a.png)

The keyboard pushes my button up. I'd rather have the keyboard obscure my screen than rearrange parts of the user interface. What is your experience with the keyboard kinda related problems?

```
// Exemptions.tsx

import React from 'react';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import {fontNumberPlate, globalStyle, heightScale} from '../../config';

import {
  Text,
  TextInput,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  View,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
} from 'react-native';

import PrimaryButton from '../../components/PrimaryButton';
import SecondaryButton from '../../components/SecondaryButton';
// import CheckOption from '../../components/CheckOption';
import RadioGroupCity from '../../components/RadioGroupCity';
import RadioGroupTime from '../../components/RadioGroupTime';
import RadioGroupPlate from '../../components/RadioGroupPlate';

export default class extends React.Component {
  AddJourneyDetails = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('AddJourneyDetails');
  };
  finish = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('AddCar');
  };

  state = {};

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = Object.assign({}, this.props.filters); // make copy and not just reference
  }

  checkBoxClick = data => {
    f = {};
    f[data.field] = !this.state[data.field];
    this.setState(f);
  };

  render() {
    const {navigation} = this.props;
    const np = navigation.getParam('np', 'No numberplate');
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.uptodown}>
          <Text style={styles.bodyboldtext}>Which LEZ did you enter?</Text>
          <RadioGroupCity />

          <Text style={styles.bodyboldtext}>When did you enter the LEZ?</Text>
          <RadioGroupTime />

          <Text style={styles.bodyboldtext}>Which car where you in?</Text>
          <RadioGroupPlate />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.buttonbox}>
          <PrimaryButton text="Next step" onPress={this.AddJourneyDetails} />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: 40,
    backgroundColor: '#FEFDF6',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  numberplateText: {
    //  flex: 1,
    width: '80%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
    ...fontNumberPlate(26),
  },
  pic: {
    width: heightScale(112),
    height: heightScale(112),
  },
  headertext: {
    fontSize: 36,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    paddingTop: 18,
    color: '#0C2238',
    paddingBottom: 20,
  },
  bodyboldtext: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#3C4C5C',
  },
  bodytext: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#3C4C5C',
  },
  textbox: {
    flex: 1,
    // backgroundColor: 'red',
    paddingTop: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonbox: {
    padding: heightScale(32),
  },
  uptodown: {
    //  backgroundColor: 'orange',
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    paddingLeft: heightScale(32),
    paddingRight: heightScale(32),
  },
});
```